# TypeError: serve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ducoment_root'

Tags: django, database

Internal Server Error: /media/productimg/1.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sajja\Envs\fyp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\sajja\Envs\fyp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: serve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ducoment_root'
[01/Sep/2021 03:39:53] "GET /static/app/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 404 1852
[01/Sep/2021 03:39:53] "GET /media/productimg/1.png HTTP/1.1" 500 60242

Comment: I am importing pictures from database t0 my website but this error  occur i don't understand what I do kindly help me

Comment: Try to change `ducoment_root` to `document_root`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.